# How to merge rows in python based on another row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

Above is my df in python. I want to merge 'text' column with referance to 'person' column
[image]

Above df is my expected outcome.

Answer (score 3):

Use `groupby` and `agg`:

```
df.groupby(df['person'].ne(df['person'].shift()).cumsum()).agg({'person': 'first', 'text': ' '.join}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

`ne` means "**n**ot **e**qual" in Pandas.

Comment: and what is `ne()` in python?

Comment: @mnm Ah, its "**n**ot **e**qual".